# Running Loop showing results

Tags: javascript

How can I use a loop to flip a coin 20 times, each time displaying the result of the flip as a string on the page? After the loop completes, I want to return the array with the result of each flip.

What I have so far:

```js
function display20Flips() {
    const results = [];
    var i;
    var results = '';
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        
}
```

```js
const coin = {
    state: 0,
    flip: function() {

        this.state = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2); 

    },
    toString: function() {

            if (this.state === 0) {
                return Heads;
            } else {
                return Tails
            }

            
    },
    toHTML: function() {
        const image = document.createElement('img');
    
        image.src = `$this.toString()}.png`
        image.alt = this.toString()
        
        return image;
    }
};
function display20Flips() {
    const results = [];
    // 4. One point: Use a loop to flip the coin 20 times, each time displaying the result of the flip as a string on the page.  After your loop completes, return an array with the result of each flip.
        for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            if(i%2){
                results[i] = 'heads';
            } else{
                results[i] = 'tails';
            }
            console.log(results[i])
        }
    }

display20Flips();
function display20Images() {
    const results = [];
    // 5. One point: Use a loop to flip the coin 20 times, and display the results of each flip as an image on the page.  After your loop completes, return an array with result of each flip.
}
```

Comment: I faced same programming code. Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want something like this:

```js
function display20Flips() {
    var results = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        if(i%2){
            results[i] = 'heads';
        } else{
            results[i] = 'tails';
        }
        console.log(results[i])
    }
}

display20Flips(); // for displaying in snippet code
```

Comment: Yes thank you so much. Can you explain how you got that answer so i can learn further ?

Comment: its not random head/tails but in sequence, so useless to use `if-else`.

Comment: Yes I know it's in sequence. He didn't ask for a random, he simply asked to flip a coin 20 times and on each flip the value should be rendered. It was in the question before the edits! :)

Comment: @brokindata The main thing here is `i%2`. The condition is working around a remainder. You see the result is either `1` r `0` which is `true` or `false` in binary, meaning an if condition can run upon it and you can have a function which can be used to do a flip like action.

Comment: @brokindata I hope I made myself clear. An addition to that you can also insert another function which can determine a total random value and with that you can also have a final random value after a coin is fliped 20 times. P.s: You can also add a little CSS animation to make it look better.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to create a FlipCoin function which determinates the value, call this function in a loop, storing the function result value in a variable, which you can print to screen and add to a results array.

something like this

```js
// Returns 1 or 0, i.e. 1 = Head, 0 = Tail
function flipCoin() {
  var flipValue =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  return flipValue % 2;
}

function main() {

  let results = [];
  for (cnt = 0; cnt < 20; cnt++) {
    let result = flipCoin();
    results.push(result);
    console.log(result == 0 ? "Tail" : "Head");
  }
  console.dir(results);

}

main();
```

Comment: Hmm...I added all my code so i already have the function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array(20)` to create an array of size 20

`Array.map` to iterate through each element, use `Array.fill` to fill the array with null values else it will not iterate through.

`Math.random()*10` to generate a random number between 0-10.

If the value is even then returned Head else `Tails`

```js
function display20Flips() {
 return Array(20).fill().map(e => Math.random()*10 & 1 ? 'Head' : 'Tails')  
}

console.log(display20Flips())
```

Comment: To advanced for me lol

Comment: No, it's not, you just need to know which function does what.

Answer (score 0):

Im not an expert but here it is :D

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<script>
var results = [];
function display20Flips() {
  for (var i = 0; i <20; i++ ){
  var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2));
  if(x == 0){
    results[i] = "heads";
  }else{
   results[i] = "tails";
  }
}
console.log(results);
}
display20Flips();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: idea here is first loop 20 times a random number between 1 - 2 if its 1 then its heads else tails.

Comment: why `1-2` not `0-1`?

Comment: you can change 1 to  0 if you want it to start with 0 not 1

Comment: don't want to change, just trying to explain that `+ 1` in `Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);` is of no use.

Comment: Why do you say its no use ?

Comment: because if you remove the + 1 there its automatically starts with 0 so you can use 0 - 1